# How to disable button behind <p:selectOneMenu> overlay

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have an upload area using p:fileupload with 3 buttons, Add Files, Upload and Cancel.  Just above this upload area, I have a p:selectOneMenu, and when the user click on the list, the dropbox menu appears, obscuring part of the 'Add Files' button.  If the user then happens to select an item that is in the area of the 'Add Files' button behind it, the window pop up letting them select a file to Add, as if the user actually presses the 'Add Files' button, and not select the item from the drop down list.  Is there a way I can disable these fileupload buttons when the dropdown menu is displayed in front of it ?  Thanks.  Primefaces 3.5.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please edit your question. Tags are not visible. And tried a newer PF version?

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and especially the part about [mcve]... cheers

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by creating an overlay div and hiding the background div if the event is destined for the selectonemenu.

Comment: Better to also upgrade your PF version. Lots of improvements since then, both in PF and JSF...